# Regex to convert JSDoc from coffeescript to javascript

Tags: perl

I'm trying to convert a project from coffeescript to javascript. I've successfully used the decaffeinate tool but something remains boring to convert manually: JSdoc comments

In coffescript we took the habit to write them like using the formalism of this example:

```
##
# This will remove the given file from the machine attachments list. If the file was previously uploaded
# to the server, it will be marked for deletion on the server. Otherwise, it will be simply truncated from
# the attachments array.
# @param file {Object} the file to delete
# @returns {boolean}
##
```

After using decaffeinate, they were transformed to something like that:

```
// #
// This will remove the given file from the machine attachments list. If the file was previously uploaded
// to the server, it will be marked for deletion on the server. Otherwise, it will be simply truncated from
// the attachments array.
// @param file {Object} the file to delete
// @returns {boolean}
// #
```

So I've tried to write a perl regex to make them look like the standard JSdoc syntax. But I'm stuck with the central lines: I can't find to way to put a star at the beginning of each lines ... Here's the best I've came to:

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" | xargs perl -0777 -i -pe 's~// #\n( +// (.+\n)+)( +)// #~/**\n$1$3 */~gm;'
```

Which results in:

```
/**
// This will remove the given file from the machine attachments list. If the file was previously uploaded
// to the server, it will be marked for deletion on the server. Otherwise, it will be simply truncated from
// the attachments array.
// @param file {Object} the file to delete
// @returns {boolean}
 */
```

But ideally, it should be transformed to:

```
/**
 * This will remove the given file from the machine attachments list. If the file was previously uploaded
 * to the server, it will be marked for deletion on the server. Otherwise, it will be simply truncated from
 * the attachments array.
 * @param file {Object} the file to delete
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
```

Here's an example of a complete file to transform: https://gist.github.com/sylvainbx/96e53b879b4dd7ef7cdd153c3fc3c5b8

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't easily do this within a single regular expression, as you need to capture and replace the first `// #` differently from the second `// #`. The following script shows how you can call a subroutine on the right hand side of the replacement and in that subroutine, you can use three simple regular expressions to convert your comment to JSdoc:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $js = <<'JS';

foo

// #
// This will remove the given file from the machine attachments list. If the file was previously uploaded
// to the server, it will be marked for deletion on the server. Otherwise, it will be simply truncated from
// the attachments array.
// @param file {Object} the file to delete
// @returns {boolean}
// #

// # List of trainings
bar

JS

sub uncomment {
    my($doc) = @_;
    $doc =~ s!^// #!/*!;
    $doc =~ s!// #$! */!;
    $doc =~ s!^//( #)?! $1 ||'' eq '#' ? '/*' : ' *' !gme;
    warn $doc;
    $doc
}

$js =~ s!(// #\R// (.+\n)+( *)// #\R)!uncomment($1)!gme;
print $js;
```

Converted to a stand-alone document-to-JSdoc pipe, the following works:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
my $js = <>;

sub uncomment {
    my($doc) = @_;
    $doc =~ s!^// #!/*!;
    $doc =~ s!// #$! */!;
    $doc =~ s!^//( #)?! $1 ||'' eq '#' ? '/*' : ' *' !gme;
    warn $doc;
    $doc
}

$js =~ s!(// #\R// (.+?\n)+( *)// #\R)!uncomment($1)!gme;
print $js;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Corion. Sadly, this is bogus because it will convert some sigle-line comments like `// # List of trainings` to `*/ List of trainings`, but it won't convert indented comments (with spaces before the //)

Comment: Thanks, I'll test tour update. I've added a link to a sample file to convert

Comment: Ok, I've changed your code a little bit to [this one](https://gist.github.com/sylvainbx/3c2a0f161b945ae1f231e69a52798e59) and it's working perfectly. I didn't know that we can use functions in substitute regex with perl, this is amazing, thanks a lot!